# How to add labels and different colors to each line in a chart?

Tags: r, plot, label

I'm trying to graph the prices of roughly 40 stocks. I want each stock to be represented by a line that's labeled by the ticker that stock's ticker and has a different color. I've written the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
stock_chart <- ggplot(Stock_Dataset, aes(Date, Close)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype=as.factor(Ticker))) +
  xlab("")
stock_chart
```

I have the following chart:

[image]

I have some of the lines labeled by their tickers but not all. Also, it looks confusing since they all have the same color. I'd appreciate any help to plot a line that looks distinct for every ticker.

Comment: use `color = as.factor(Ticker)` inside `aes`

Comment: Thanks that did give each one a different color. For some of them the colors look very similar though, so it gets hard to distinguish. I was wondering if there's a way to choose the colors to look a little starker, or have each ticker name appear next to its line on the actual chart as well?

Answer (score 0):

See `linetype` geom has a limitation. as per [documentation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_linetype_size_shape.html)

> The linetype aesthetic can be specified with either an integer (0-6), a name (0 = blank, 1 = solid, 2 = dashed, 3 = dotted, 4 = dotdash, 5 = longdash, 6 = twodash), a mapping to a discrete variable, or a string of an even number (up to eight) of hexadecimal digits which give the lengths in consecutive positions in the string. See examples for a hex string demonstration.

What you could do to include color is something like this

```
ggplot(Stock_Dataset, aes(Date, Close)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype=as.factor(Ticker), color = Ticker)) +
  xlab("")
```

---

Since you haven't added any data I am showing you on `economics_long`

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggrepel)

economics_long %>%
  group_by(variable) %>%
  mutate(label = ifelse(date == max(date), variable, NA)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = value01, color = variable, label = label)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_label_repel(aes(label = label),
                   nudge_x = 1,
                   na.rm = TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-06-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>